# Swapping components in React

Tags: reactjs, components, react-redux

In my ReactJS project I have a MainComponent which contains some ChildComponents as written down in my example. I am searching for a smooth way to 'swap' the ChildComponents via a button up/down.

I have checked out 'react-sortable-hoc' but this seems just handling dragging by mouse or touch, I am searching for a swap via click events such as a button containing move up / move down.

```
- MainComponent
  - ChildComponent #1 [up / down]
  - ChildComponent #2 [up / down]
  - ChildComponent #3 [up / down]
  - ChildComponent #4 [up / down]
```

Is there any such suggested lib's or ways to archive something like this?

Comment: Have you checked [CSS-Transition-Group](https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group)?

Answer (score 0):

I would simply swap the order of your `ChildComponent`, but make sure to manage `keys` props of each `ChildComponent` correctly.

So that, assuming your `ChildComponent` is rendered by:

```
arrays.map(x => <ChildComponent keys={x.id} />)
```

Make sure to use the key not based on `array` index.
Say, for example, swap 2nd and 3rd:

```
let 2nd = arrays[1], 3rd = arrays[2];
array[2] = 2nd;
array[1] = 3rd;
```

You can then focus on updating `array`. If you want some more transition, it's worth to try [reactcss-transition-group](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html#high-level-api-reactcsstransitiongroup).

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I will take a look at it!

Comment: Created myself a function for swapping components but I just don't find out how to create that smooth transition of movement when the state has changed and components are re-ordered. Could you provide an example of how to do this?